# XML string too large to download with dyplr & dbgetquery(). Is there a way to parse XML without downloading the XML text?

Tags: r, xml, dplyr, xml-parsing

I have XML string on a server. I would like to parse the XML using R. My code, so far, runs a SQL query with a limit of 20 rows. When I download the results as a data frame the XML string is too long and the text is truncated causing `read_xml`to throw an error. Any suggestions how to get around this issue? Do I need to download the results to parse it?

Here is my code:

```
drv <- odbc::odbc()
impala <- src_impala(
            drv = drv,
            driver = "Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala",
            host = "host",
            dbname = "default",
            port = 21050)
sqlResults = dbGetQuery(impala,sqlQuery)    
data=sqlResults[2,10]
xmlText=as.character(data)
read_xml(xmlText)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message and provide more information about your variable data, maybe a sample?  I believe there might be a formatting issue that is causing the error not the length of the record.

Comment: I am quite certain that it is a length issue. The error is: "Premature end of data in tag QuantitativeResult line 1". If I look at the text I see that the XML String is truncated in the middle with no closing node for "QuantitativeResult"  . The read_xml read other shorter strings perfectly fine.

Comment: There must be a way to parse without downloading or to allow for more memory in the data frame. No? Downloading to a .csv file creates the same problem as there is a limit to the number of characters in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I was able to use `substring` in my query to create multiple columns with subsets of the XML string. I then ran the query with `dyplr` and downloaded the results. Next, I used the unite function in `tidyr` to concatenate the strings to a complete XML string. Finally, I was then able to parse the XML with R's `read_xml`.
My query looked something like this:

```
Select 
  (substr(xmlText,1,30000))'xmlText1',
  (substr(xmlText,30001,30000))'xmlText2',
  (substr(xmlText,60001,30000))'xmlText3',
  (substr(xmlText,90001,30000))'xmlText4',
  (substr(xmlText,120001,30000))'xmlText5'
From
  myXMLtables
```